# ASP.NET MVC returns damaged zipped file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, http-headers, zip

I'm trying to download zip file. But downloaded zip file is damaged or corrupted and I can't open it.
I use `Ionic.Zip` library for create my `File.zip`. My code:

```
public static Stream LoadImages(int[] ids)
{
    var images = new List<byte[]>();
    var imgNames = new List<string>();

    foreach (var id in ids)
    {
        string fName;
        images.Add(LoadImage(id, out fName));
        imgNames.Add(fName);
    }

    MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();

    using (var zip = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < images.Count; i++)
        {
            zip.AddEntry(imgNames[i], images[i]);
        }

        zip.Save(outputStream);
    }
    return outputStream;
}
```

And my Controller action:

```
public FileResult DownloadGallery(int[] ids)
{
    var stream = ImageManager.LoadImages(ids);
    return File(stream, "application/zip", "gallery.zip");
}
```

Maybe my `zip file` incorrect or problem in my `Http Response`...
Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rewind your `MemoryStream` back to the beginning:

```
public FileResult DownloadGallery(int[] ids)
{
    var stream = ImageManager.LoadImages(ids);
    stream.Position = 0;
    return File(stream, "application/zip", "gallery.zip");
}
```

The `FileResult` only starts writing from the stream where ever its current position is.